# Show the processed data from Pandas in HTML page using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

The data format of my CSV file is mentioned below:

```
API Name                Test Result    Risk Rating    Vulnerability Category

https://api-test.com      FAIL           LOW          Information Gathering
https://api-test1.com     PASS           MEDIUM       Authentication Test
https://api-test2.com     SKIP           HIGH         Web Service
https://api-test1.com     FAIL           CRITICAL     Configuration Management
https://api-test2.com     PASS           MEDIUM       Configuration Management
https://api-test.com      PASS           CRITICAL     Web Service
```

Now, what I want is to show all the data of particular API in table using Plotly. So, when I click the link of an API, it should show the data of that API in a nice table. For ex. If I click API https://api-test2.com, it should show:

```
API Name                Test Result    Risk Rating    Vulnerability Category

https://api-test2.com     SKIP           HIGH         Web Service
https://api-test2.com     PASS           MEDIUM       Configuration Management
```

I am able to process data in the required format from Pandas and print on the console but not able to show that on html page. The code of my Pandas processing is mentioned below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',)
apis = df_new['API Name'].unique()
for api in apis:
     print(df_new.loc[df['API Name'] == api])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why this is being downvoted. I don't understand. I have given all the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you store data in DataFrame [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) is probably what you need.

Comment: My solution is bit complex. I have shared the exact requirement in my question. Just .to_html() will not resolve my problem.